# Why are consecutive integer variables not 4 bytes apart in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int varInt = 123456;
   string varString = "DefaultString";

   cout << "varInt (0x" << &varInt << ") = " << varInt << endl;
   cout << "varString (0x" << &varString << ") = " << varString << endl;
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

My question is: Since an integer is 4 bytes, shouldn't the variable varString be located 4 bytes away in memory from varInt? I.E. varString should be located at 0x0000002**7** 2B F7 F4 44

Comment: There is no guarantee at all how the compiler will layout different variables. They don't even need to be in the same order. It is not something that a valid C++ program can observe. There is no reason to expect any particular relative location.

Comment: [can't replicate](https://godbolt.org/z/TnPYx7jzz), it depends on CPU architecture and operating system and compiler.

Comment: Your code doesn't have `consecutive integer variables`.

Comment: `I.E. varString should be located at 0x00000027 2B F7 F4 44` That would be four _Gigabytes_ after  `0x000000262BF7F444`.

Comment: There are no rules in C++ about where different variables must be placed relative to each other in memory.

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is likely 24 leading the compiler to place it at an address which is a multiple of 24

Comment: What is your compiler, optimization options, and a CPU architecture?

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with [tag:compiler-construction], and nothing at all to do with [tag:operating-system].

Comment: FYI, variables don't need to be allocated in memory.  Most processors have registers.  The compiler is free to allocate variables using registers and registers don't have addresses.  The registers don't need to be consecutive either.  The compiler is also allowed to place constants anywhere that is addressable, including in the executable.  the exception to the register usage is when you take the address of a variable; then the compiler must put the variables in an addressable area (registers don't have addresses).

Comment: @AhmedAEK isn't that 4 bits, not 4 bytes? (the difference between the two addresses)

Comment: @DanielLangr This is a debug x64 run on VS 2022. On a previous project I followed 0.1-0.12 at learncpp.com and that was a few weeks ago, I don't remember if I changed any settings

Comment: Compile for release x86 and you'll see the variables are indeed 4 bytes apart. Compile for  release/x64 and you'll see the variables are 8 bytes apart. Debug builds and to a certain degree, retail builds, will put in padding between variables. Not just for better memory alignment, but also to catch buffer overruns. (e.g. crash faster when you write past a valid address).

Answer (score 2):

C++ as a language doesn't give a guarantee to where stack-variables (locals) are places. So your results will vary depending on the OS, the architecture, the compiler, the optimization settings...
As long as you don't try to take it's address, an integer-variable is not even guaranteed to be at any address, and can instead be hoisted into a register, if the function allows for it, and optimization is used.

As for why the string-variable will practically be more than 4 bytes away: Alignment. The compiler will try to place variables at an address, that is a multiple of their natural alignment. The details will also depend on your environment, but as a rule of thumb, the alignment for x64 is 8 byte, and any struct larger or equal than 8 byte will be placed at such aligned addresses. The modulo of the address of "varString" that you shown is aligned to 8 byte, as (address % 8) == 0. If it were to be placed at the address you suggested, that alignment would not be given.

I'm not an expert on the technical details of alignment, but it's done mostly for performance reasons. I think much older CPUs couldn't even process unaligned addresses, more recent ones had a hidden penality, and on modern CPUs I think there is not much of a penality, unless you cross a cache-line boundary while trying to access a value (which doesn't happen when things are aligned).
Things are different when we are talking about 16-byte types that are processed via XMM, in which case alignment is still pretty necessary for performance (or could even seg-fault on certain instructions if not kept).

So the bottom line is, the compiler will not attempt to preserve as much space as possible, especially with local variables, but instead attempt to achieve alignments. Last time I checked, debug-builds of MSVC will not even attempt to reuse the space of a local variable after it has been freed (ie. when declared within a {}, or not used anymore), but as mentioned before, this is all up to implementations.

Comment: Do note that "stack-variables" are actually called objects with automatic storage duration.  While a stack is a way to accomplish this, it would be 100% legal for the compiler to new every object at the start and delete them at the end, causing all objects to be on the "heap".  They aren't going to for performance reasons, but the option is still there.

Comment: I wonder how alignment could explain the objects being 36 bytes apart.  Maybe the string is being assigned at a multiple of sizeof(string)?

Comment: ARM CPUs will definitely barf if you try to access an unaligned integer.  On x86 the CPU's basic operations can access unaligned integers (with some performance penalty) but you can still run into problems if the optimizer decides to emit some SIMD instructions to speed things up, as the SIMD commands won't work correctly for unaligned objects.

Comment: FYI, compilers are allowed to use registers for variables.  This blows away all theories of memory placement, since registers don't have addresses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple to me. The compiler must allocate space for the string object (probably 12 or 16 bytes) and also space for the contents-- A minimum of 14 bytes. It probably picked 28 bytes for contents (just under twice the size initialized).

Comment: FWIW x86-64 clang and gcc both report `std::string` to be 32 bytes

Comment: The difference between those reported addresses is 0x24 = 36 bytes. The size of `std::string` in x64 and MS STL is 32 bytes and SSO is applied with the buffer capacity 15, so no additional bytes seem to be allocated in OP's case. (Even if they were, they would be allocated on the heap.)